# Allocate more disk space to Ubuntu

Tags: disk, disk-management

I'm having 2 OS installed on my DELL laptop: Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, each takes 50% disk space of my hard disk. Now I want to increase that of Ubuntu. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer of Toivo Muukonen. You can use GParted and make backups.
Additional information:
You can only resize partitions on the right side of them. So if you have e.g. 500 for Windows en 500 for Ubuntu (-----/----- (each - is 100GB)) you can resize 500 Windows to 400. The result is 400 Windows, 100 Unallocated and 500 Ubuntu (----/-/-----).
Now you want to add the 100 unallocated to 500 Ubuntu. To do that you need to move the 500 Ubuntu to the left. Result 400 Windows, 500 Ubuntu and 100 unallocated (----/-----/-).
Now you can enlarge the 500 Ubuntu with the unallocated (100) space. Resulting in 400 Windows and 600 Ubuntu (----/------).  
I would advise to resize your Windows partition (NTFS) in Windows with diskmanager. Not that GParted cannot do the job, but lets use Windows-tools for Windows partitions and GParted for Linux partitions ( EXT2, EXT4, BTRFS ).
And again, if you can make backups before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember to back up important data!**

You can boot to a LiveCD or LiveUSB drive in *try me* mode.

Load gparted which should be installed by default, if not you can apt-get it.

Resize your partititions: right click, click resize, follow the instructions.

Click Apply and wait.

Reboot and take the CD/USB out when it tells you to.

I hope this helps!